# How to find location using postal code in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hei

iam working with google map have done with searching part and getting results when search by city name.Now i have to do extend functionality something like if i give postnumber and then have to search in 2km or 10km area .How can i do it ??
see one example here
http://www.hm.com/no/store-locator

Answer (score 2):

*Try this code*...

that is getting **latitude & longitude** from **Postcode**...

```
public void locationFromPostCode(String postCode){

    geocoder1 = new Geocoder(this);
    try {
          List<Address> addresses1 = geocoder1.getFromLocationName(postCode, 1);
          if (addresses1 != null && !addresses1.isEmpty()) {
            Address address1 = addresses1.get(0);
            // Use the address as needed
            latitude_start = address1.getLatitude();
            longitude_start = address1.getLongitude();
            String message = "Latitude: "+address1.getLatitude()+", Longitude: "+address1.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else {
            // Display appropriate message when Geocoder services are not available
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to geocode zipcode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // handle exception
        }
    }
```

For that code you *require* following ...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

You getting from this code *latitude & longitude* of **Postcode place**
From *latitude & longitude* you can get the **Location**...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it is not polite - and not acceptable - to ask for votes/accepts. If the OP wants to vote or accept, they will. I am removing that text from your question. Please don't do this in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function geocode_yahoo($code){  
    $app_id = ''; 
    $code = str_replace(" ","+",$code); 

    $url ="http://local.yahooapis.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?appid=$app_id&zip=$code"; 
    $xml=@file_get_contents($url); 
    preg_match('/<Latitude>(.*?)<\/Latitude>/',$xml,$matches); 
    $ll['lat']=$matches[1]; 
    preg_match('/<Longitude>(.*?)<\/Longitude>/',$xml,$matches); 
    $ll['lng']=$matches[1]; 
    return $ll; 
}
```

here is the function that will return lat and long , I think you will work on that. 
Register at yahoo for an api key. and use this function. been using it for months.

There are odd occasions it geocodes wrong, but it's only occasional and the easiest way to find out, is they are normally 100's of miles out (so the lat longs are totally different)

We also use the AFD postcode database (put in postcode - get all address details) this has lat longs in, but only to 4 decimal places (not terribly accurate)